# SCD TYPE 2 Implementation

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse, scd, sql-data-warehouse

Needs to implement SCD TYPE 2 Table in SQL server.

Which insert new record and update timestamp if Threshold Values changes for particular Band.

If no changes found then doesn't touch the entry.

| Band | Value | StartDt | Enddt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Junior | 2000 | 1-1-2021 | 31-12-9999 |
| Senior | 3000 | 1-1-2021 | 31-12-9999 |

| BAND | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Junior | 2500 |
| Senior | 3000 |

Now I wants to update and insert Junior Record

| Band | Value | StartDt | Enddt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Junior | 2000 | 1-1-2021 | Getdate() - 1 |
| Junior | 2500 | Getdate() | 31-12-9999 |
| Senior | 3000 | 1-1-2021 | 31-12-9999 |

Looking for results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
USE [DBTest]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[LOAD_IVA_Agent_Master]    Script Date: 24-08-2023 15:31:48 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LOAD_IVA_Agent_Master]
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY

DECLARE @cmd AS VARCHAR(1000)

PRINT('At 1')
DROP table IF EXISTS #STG_VS_Threshold

Select * into #STG_VS_Threshold from Threshold

Print('Complete 2')

SELECT 
HASHBYTES('MD5', CONCAT(
ISNULL(BAND,'NA') ,
ISNULL(StartVal,0),
ISNULL(EndVal,0) 
) )  AS MD5,
* ,Getdate() as Update_Date, CAST('9999-12-31' AS DATE) AS EFF_END_DT into #V_STG_VS_Agent_Master FROM #STG_VS_Threshold

Print('Complete 3')
DROP table IF EXISTS STG_VS_Agent_Master_BKP 
Select * into STG_VS_Agent_Master_BKP from #V_STG_VS_Agent_Master

UPDATE MAIN   
SET EFF_END_DT = GETDATE()-1
FROM STG_VS_Agent_Master AS MAIN
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #V_STG_VS_Agent_Master STG WHERE (STG.Band = MAIN.Band) AND STG.MD5 <> MAIN.MD5 AND MAIN.EFF_END_DT = CAST('9999-12-31' AS DATE) )
   

INSERT INTO STG_VS_Agent_Master
SELECT  * FROM #V_STG_VS_Agent_Master STG
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM STG_VS_Agent_Master MAIN WHERE (STG.Band = MAIN.Band) AND MAIN.EFF_END_DT = CAST('9999-12-31' AS DATE)  )

DROP table STG_VS_Agent_Master_BKP

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
print ('Some error into the code')
END CATCH
END 
GO
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).